# Join the same column together if everything else in the row is identical sql

Tags: sql

I have a data set where all the other information in the row is identical except for one column "Issues" as there can be multiple issues but each issue gets put in to a new row. I'd like to join those rows if everything else in that row is identical. I've found solutions to join different columns together but can't quite get it for the same column being joined if everything else is the same. The column is a character string.

Example Data:

| DateTime | StaffID | ClientID | Enquiry | Issue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25/08/2022 15:55 | 79 | 001 | Relationship | Behaviour |
| 25/08/2022 15:55 | 79 | 001 | Relationship | Social |
| 25/08/2022 15:55 | 79 | 001 | Relationship | Child |
| 25/08/2022 15:55 | 79 | 001 | Relationship | Anxiety |
| 25/08/2022 10:15 | 450 | 002 | Sleep | Feeding |
| 25/08/2022 10:15 | 450 | 002 | Sleep | Settle |

Outcome I'd like to create:
I want to join the 'Issue' column where the other columns are the same

| DateTime | StaffID | ClientID | Enquiry | Issue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25/08/2022 15:55 | 79 | 001 | Relationship | Behaviour, Social, Child, Anxiety |
| 25/08/2022 10:15 | 450 | 002 | Sleep | Feeding, Settle |

Comment: Please add sample data, what you've tried, desired result

Comment: Nothing in your question indicates SQLSERVER.  Please tag with the DB you are using.  Note that in Oracle, for example, that same function is called LISTAGG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out, but do note that, STRING_AGG() applies to SQL Server 2017 (14.x) and later

```
SELECT DateTime, StaffID, ClientID, Enquiry, STRING_AGG(Issue, ', ') AS Issues
FROM TableName
GROUP BY DateTime, StaffID, ClientID, Enquiry
```

Please read documentation for [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

*STRING_AGG ( expression, separator )*

Since you want to join two or more values of the column issue, you just need to change expression to issue, and your separator, for instance, comma is my separator

Comment: Awesome function, thank you for sharing. Would you not need to GROUP BY DateTime and Enquiry too?

Comment: @L.Newell Yes, those would need to be either grouped or aggregated.

Comment: @L.Newell, oh ya, I'm sorry, miss that out!

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed for it to work! STRING_AGG(Issue) and GROUP BY (all other columns)